# Updating httpcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext, claims-based-identity

I am having some trouble changing User in httpcontext. I run through a module first and set the claimsprincipal there then go to my webfrom which then reads the claimsprincipal. Unfortunately the web from reads the user as it was when it came in before I messed with it in the module. Debugged it and the end of the module shows what I want the claimsprincipal to be so I don't know where I am messing up.

module.cs

```
HttpContext current1 = HttpContext.Current;
//Changing principal
current1.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); //This shows the right principal
```

webform.aspx.cs

```
claimsPrincipal = Page.User as ClaimsPrincipal; //Shows old principal
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code where you set the principal?

Comment: Its extremely long and involves many classes. What I can tell you is that hovering over ApplicationInstance:User:ClaimsPrincipal:Claims:ResultsView shows me exactly what I want to be passed to the webform.